# Building NGINX with --with-cpu-opt?

Tags: nginx, gcc, makefile, nginx-config

I am in the process of building NGINX, and am looking at the `--with-cpu-opt`.
From what I can find there are hidden valid options like amd64, however, I can not see the normally used generic referenced anywhere in the Makefile, nor can I see where to find more details on what values are valid and what they do. It seems not to be documented nor can I find a path in the sources.

What are the valid values and their consequences?